# Changing Directory Using Renci.SshNet

Tags: c#, linux

Why cant I change directories using Renci.SshNet?

I want to automate some things i am doing on a linux server and ran into a huge hiccup. I read a few articles and decided to use Renci.SshNet to complete this goal. I am building a C# WinForm app where I am able to successfully connect to the server, add and remove files but i cannot seem to be able to change directories. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
private void btn_Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = Environment.UserName;
    string pwd = txtPassword.Text;
    string location = "Linux_Server";
    string myPath = "cd /home/User1/Folder1";
    using (var client = new SshClient(location, user, pwd))
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            var cmd = client.RunCommand(myPath);
            MessageBox.Show("output = " + cmd.Result.ToString()); //Directory Currently Shows /home/User1 I want it to go into Folder1
            client.RunCommand("touch test.txt"); //Works 
            client.RunCommand("rm test.txt"); //Works
            client.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + err.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment i want the file to be added and removed at the desired path location

Comment: Does .RunCommand return value? How do you handle a success or fail of its execution?

Comment: In this instance, it does not but if I were to say run the following command ifconfig, it would return the value in the command line interface.